# MODX not sending emails

Tags: php, email, modx-revolution

I'm using modMail class to send custom emails. I have followed the guidelines on MODX site and used the following code which I placed in a snippet:

```
$message = $modx->getChunk('myEmailTemplate');

$modx->getService('mail', 'mail.modPHPMailer');
$modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_BODY,$message);
$modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_FROM,'me@example.org');
$modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_FROM_NAME,'Johnny Tester');
$modx->mail->set(modMail::MAIL_SUBJECT,'Check out my new email template!');
$modx->mail->address('to','user@example.com');
$modx->mail->address('reply-to','me@xexample.org');
$modx->mail->setHTML(true);
if (!$modx->mail->send()) {
    $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,'An error occurred while trying to send the email: '.$modx->mail->mailer->ErrorInfo);
}
$modx->mail->reset();
```

The snippet has been modified to contain message from custom chunk as well as email addresses have been replaced with the correct ones. The snippet sent email once and never again. I have no idea what causes such behavior which prevents it from sending emails.

I have read that using the reset function `$modx->mail->reset();` resets email fields and allows the email to be sent again yet I have a feeling that it causes problem here.

The snippet is called uncached on the page `[[!email]]`

Does anyone have an idea why the emails are not being sent, even though it worked once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is an error in your chunk or in processing your chunk, modx is never going to get to thepoint where it logs an error. try something like:

```
if (!$modx->mail->send()) {
    $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,'An error occurred while trying to send the email: '.$modx->mail->mailer->ErrorInfo);
}else{
 $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR,'This mail was sent: '.$message);
}
```

to see if it logs something. but otherwise what you have there is exactly correct - try to take the $message variable out and send just a string. if it sent mail once, then something else must be wrong. I'd start looking at mail server logs, headers, spam [gmail??] etc.

Comment: Thats a good point, but I have checked the error log and it does not have any report for the modmail class. However I managed to solve the problem by turning off caching for the resource that was containing the snippet sending an email. What it shows, is the fact that the snippet does not reset email fields once cached. Thanks!

Comment: ahh that sneaky cache, I always forget to check it first. also - the logging, when the site goes live; be sure to clear the error log and set the logging to 0, as those log files can be publicly available. [just FYI]